# set only small properties in Zurb Foundation and let medium and large column be the size of their content

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have been trying to create a menu where all menu items take their text length on large and medium window size but take 12 column when the window is small. I use Zurb Foundation as the title says.

Here is the interesting part of the code using slim. please mind the right class which give float:right css attributes to the object

```
a.menu-item-right.column.right.small-12.medium-1 href="#" LINKLlaksdlkasdja
a.menu-item-right.column.right.small-12.medium-1 href="#" LINKLlaksdlkasdja
a.menu-item-right.column.right.small-12.medium-1 href="#" LINKLlaksdlkasdja
a.menu-item-right.column.tight.small-12.medium-1 href="#" LINKLlaksdlkasdja
```

or

```
<a class="menu-item-right column right small-12 medium-1" href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
<a class="menu-item-right column right small-12 medium-1" href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
<a class="menu-item-right column right small-12 medium-1" href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
<a class="menu-item-right column right small-12 medium-1" href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
```

if you prefer.

Sadly (right now), it is a feature of Foundation to perpetuate small behaviour to lager one when nothing else is specify. Specifying medium-1 makes all button stack weirdly as predicted.

How would you implement this cleanly?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it myself and posting it here if it can help somebody. It was pretty easy finally.
Answer:

```
    nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="data-topbar"
      ul.title-area
        li.name
        li.toggle-topbar.menu-icon
          a href="#"
            span Menu
      section.top-bar-section
        ul.right
          li
            a href="#" Artists
          li
            a href="#" Symposiums
          li
            a href="#" Galeries
          li
            a href="#" Mon Portail
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can simply use `medium-centered`
http://jsfiddle.net/3MUDv/

```
<div class="wrapper row">
<a class="menu-item-right column small-12 medium-centered " href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
<a class="menu-item-right column small-12 medium-centered " href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
<a class="menu-item-right column small-12 medium-centered " href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
<a class="menu-item-right column small-12 medium-centered " href="#">LINKLlaksdlkasdja</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Hi, tank you very much, it is almost that! I have updated the question; it happens that I wanted to have the element float to the right. This last information breaks your solution for me.

Comment: thank you very much, you made me thinking about it from otehr point of view. this is my answer: Using <ul class="inline"> and <li>